# Top of the screen when the app is running showing a label with the app title

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

[image]

Guys please, I don't know what to do, suddenly this label on the top appeared with the text which is actually the title of my application.
I tried searching on the internet and stack overflow, but I found nothing but another question with the same problem which wasn't resolved.
This is my home file, but I actually believe it is a problem in the manifest.xml file

```
    import 'dart:async';
import 'package:dices_app/icons/d6_icons.dart';
import 'package:dices_app/icons/d8_icons.dart';
import 'package:dices_app/icons/percent_icons.dart';
import 'package:firebase_admob/firebase_admob.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'icons/dices_icons.dart';
import 'functions.dart';
import 'icons/skulls_icons.dart';
import 'icons/nice_icons_icons.dart';
import 'history.dart';
import 'dice.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:firebase_admob/firebase_admob.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

String AD_REWARDED_ID = 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917';
String AD_BANNER_ID = 'ca-app-pub-6798357699412375/6371632425';
String AD_INTERSTITIAL_ID = 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712';
String APP_ID = 'ca-app-pub-6798357699412375~3611228404';
RewardedVideoAd videoAd = RewardedVideoAd.instance;
InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
BannerAd myBanner = BannerAd(
    adUnitId: BannerAd.testAdUnitId,
    size: AdSize.smartBanner,
    listener: (event) => ('banner event is $event'),
    targetingInfo: targetingInfo
);
InterstitialAd myInterstitial() {
  return InterstitialAd(
    adUnitId: InterstitialAd.testAdUnitId,
    targetingInfo: targetingInfo,
    listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
      if (event == MobileAdEvent.failedToLoad) {
        interstitialAd..load();
      } else if (event == MobileAdEvent.closed) {
        interstitialAd = myInterstitial()..load();
      }
    },
  );
}
Color bgColor = isDarkMode ? Color(0x2D050401) : Color(0xff03ed19);
Color appBarColor = isDarkMode ? Colors.grey[900] : Color(0xd66a994e);
Color iconColor = isDarkMode ? Color(0xE9F02D3A) : Colors.black;
Color textColor = isDarkMode ? Color(0xE9F02D3A) : Colors.black;
Color cardColor = isDarkMode ? Colors.white10 : Colors.white;
Color buttonColor = isDarkMode ? Colors.grey[900] : Colors.grey[350];

MobileAdTargetingInfo targetingInfo = MobileAdTargetingInfo(
  keywords: <String>['games', 'dices', 'random', 'boardgames'],
  childDirected: false,
);

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}
bool noAds = false;
bool switchValue = true;
bool isDarkMode = true;

class _HomeState extends State<Home> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;
  List<Tab> tabs = <Tab>[
    Tab(
      child: Text(
        'Dices',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
      ),
    ),
    Tab(
      child: Text(
        'History',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
      ),
    ),
  ];

  @override
  void dispose() {
    interstitialAd?.dispose();
    if (noAds == true) {
      myBanner?.dispose();
      super.dispose();
    }
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    noAds = false;
    FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: FirebaseAdMob.testAppId);
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: tabs.length);
    if (noAds != true) {
      myBanner
        ..load()
        ..show(
          // Positions the banner ad 60 pixels from the bottom of the screen
          anchorType: AnchorType.bottom,
        );
    }

    interstitialAd = myInterstitial()..load();

    videoAd.load(adUnitId: AD_REWARDED_ID);
    videoAd.listener =
        (RewardedVideoAdEvent event, {String rewardType, int rewardAmount}) {
      print('rewarded video ad $event');
      if (event == RewardedVideoAdEvent.rewarded) {
        noAds = true;
        Timer(Duration(minutes: rewardAmount), () {
          noAds = false;
        });
      }
      if (event == RewardedVideoAdEvent.closed) {
        videoAd.load(adUnitId: RewardedVideoAd.testAdUnitId);
      }
    };
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: appBarColor,
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: iconColor),
          bottom: TabBar(
            controller: _tabController,
            tabs: tabs,
            labelColor: textColor,
            indicatorColor: iconColor,
          ),
        ),
        drawer: Drawer(
            child: Container(
                color: isDarkMode ? Colors.grey[900] : Color(0x35A6A6A8),
                child: ListView(children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 50,
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      'DarkMode  /  Light Mode',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: textColor,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 20,
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),

                    subtitle: Stack(alignment: Alignment.center, children: [
                      Switch(
                        value: switchValue,
                        onChanged: (val) {
                          setState(() {
                            isDarkMode = val;
                            switchValue = val;
                            bgColor = isDarkMode
                                ? Color(0x2D050401)
                                : Color(0xff03ed19);
                            appBarColor = isDarkMode
                                ? Colors.grey[900]
                                : Color(0xd66a994e);
                            iconColor = isDarkMode
                                ? Color(0xE9F02D3A)
                                : Colors.black;
                            textColor =
                                isDarkMode ? Color(0xE9F02D3A) : Colors.black;
                            cardColor =
                                isDarkMode ? Colors.white10 : Colors.white;
                            buttonColor = isDarkMode
                                ? Colors.grey[900]
                                : Colors.grey[350];
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ]),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Divider(color: Colors.black,),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Column(children: [
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        'Watch a video to get 30 minutes of no ads',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            color: textColor,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                      onTap: () {
                      },
                    ),

                    FlatButton.icon(
                      icon: Icon(
                          Icons.play_circle_filled,
                          size: 80,
                        ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        videoAd.show();
                      }, label: Text(''),
                    ),
                  ])
                ]))),
        backgroundColor: bgColor,
        body: Container(
          //height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 60,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
          child: TabBarView(controller: _tabController, children: [
            ListView(children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Dice(
                          icon: D6.dice_6,
                          func: roll6,
                          type: 'D6',
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20.0,
                        ),
                        Text('       6 faced dice',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black)),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20.0,
                        ),
                        Dice(
                          icon: NiceIcons.d4,
                          func: roll4,
                          type: 'D4',
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20.0,
                        ),
                        Text('       4 faced dice',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black)),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20.0,
                        ),
                        Dice(
                          icon: NiceIcons.d20,
                          func: roll20,
                          type: 'D20',
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20.0,
                        ),
                        Text('       20 faced dice',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black)),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20.0,
                        ),
                        Dice(
                          icon: NiceIcons.d10,
                          func: roll10,
                          type: 'D10',
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20.0,
                        ),
                        Text('          10 faced dice',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black)),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20.0,
                        ),
                        Dice(
                          type: 'D8',
                          func: roll8,
                          icon: D8.dice_eight_faces_eight,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20.0,
                        ),
                        Text('          8 faced dice',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black)),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20.0,
                        ),
                        Dice(
                          func: cluedo,
                          icon: cluedoIcon,
                          type: 'Cluedo',
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20.0,
                        ),
                        Text('          Cluedo dices',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black)),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20.0,
                        ),
                      ]),
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Dice(
                        icon: Skulls.monetization_on,
                        func: flipACoin,
                        type: 'Coin Flip',
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20.0,
                      ),
                      Text('Flip a coin              ',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black)),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20.0,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          FlatButton.icon(
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/xfaced',
                                  arguments: {
                                    'isDarkMode': isDarkMode,
                                  });
                            },
                            icon: Icon(
                              NiceIcons.xfaced,
                              size: 120,
                              color: iconColor,
                            ),
                            label: Text(''),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20.0,
                      ),
                      Text('X faced dice            ',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                          )),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20.0,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          FlatButton.icon(
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/deathroll',
                                  arguments: {
                                    'isDarkMode': isDarkMode,
                                  });
                            },
                            icon: Icon(
                              Skulls.skull,
                              size: 120,
                              color: iconColor,
                            ),
                            label: Text(''),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20.0,
                      ),
                      Text('Roll to death!            ',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                          )),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20.0,
                      ),
                      Dice(
                        type: 'D12',
                        func: roll12,
                        icon: NiceIcons.d12,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20.0,
                      ),
                      Text('12 faced dice           ',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black)),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20.0,
                      ),
                      Dice(
                        type: 'Monopoly Speedy',
                        image: Image.asset(
                          'images/pngbarn.png',
                          scale: 4,
                        ),
                        func: speedy,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20.0,
                      ),
                      Text('Monopoly Dices + speedy',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black)),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20.0,
                      ),
                      Dice(
                        type: 'D%',
                        icon: Percent.percent,
                        func: rollPercent,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20.0,
                      ),
                      Text('          Percent dice            ',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black)),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20.0,
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ]),
            History()
          ]),
        ));
  }
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.ongar.dices_app">
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="Dice Mania"
        android:icon="@mipmap/dice_fire">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-6798357699412375~3611228404"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->

            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your XML style  file you should define these:

```
<style name="YourStyleName" parent="parentStyle">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Then restart, and it should work.

Comment: I think I deleted that like a stupid in fact from when I deleted it it show this, so I have to create another one?

Comment: Yes, you should make another one, and in the Manifest declare         android:theme="@style/YourStyleName" in the application tag.

Comment: When i add these lines on a new styles.xml file it says element style must be declared and when I run it doesnt work, sorry but im not familiar with xml.

Comment: I added these lines inside the resources brackets, but now I get this error `FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     AAPT: error: resource style/parentStyle (aka com.ongar.dices_app:style/parentStyle) not found.
     error: failed linking references.`

Comment: That's because parentstyle doesn't exist, I wrote parentstyle but it had to be replaced. Default should be parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar". Try using that one.

Comment: I did everything but still I get this error: `FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     /Users/giordanoragnacci/AndroidStudioProjects/dices_app/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-47:19: AAPT: error: '@styles/YourStyleName' is incompatible with attribute theme (attr) reference.`, please if you can give an answer quickly

Comment: Instead of @styles/... use @style/..., without the s.

Comment: Still giving me: `* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed /Users/giordanoragnacci/AndroidStudioProjects/dices_app/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-47:19: AAPT: error: resource style/YourStyleName (aka com.ongar.dices_app:style/YourStyleName) not found.`

Comment: apparently, I had  to put the file inside the values folder that I had deleted before. Sorry I know that I was really stupid with my question but I'm not an expert of xml so thank you for your patience and I hope that this thread will  be useful to all the flutter devs of the future

Comment: Yea i thought it wasn't necessary to say that, good thing you searched! This is still some experience with XML so keep it up, and don't delete stuff randomly ;D

Comment: @Fede I tried this but not working in my case, Will you please help?

Answer (score 1):

In my case the the file `styles.xml` was present in the `values-night` folder but not in the `values` folder, so I copied and pasted it there and it was solved. This is how my `styles.xml` looks btw. Special atention to the `parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"` attribute on each one:

[image]