# Unwanted app title and background strip show above appbar

Tags: android, flutter

A few weeks ago this weird black strip with my app title appeared above the appbar on the Android half of my Flutter app. I thought it was only on my android emulator because it isn't on the ios emulator, or on my physical pixel 4a. But, someone else installed my production app off the play store and it is showing on his android phone.

**This is how it does look. You can see it is between the status and app bars:**

[image]

**And this is how it should look(no bar):**

[image]

That makes me think it has to be in my code, but I didn't add it, and I've looked everywhere and can't find it. And why is it only on some devices.

- It shows on every screen but the splash screen
- It's always the same color(1A1C1E) no matter if the app is in light or dark mode, or what color the app is set to(I have a color picker)
- All my appbars are transparent. If I add color to them, the strip is still 1A1C1E and the appbar color shows below. This tells me it's not related to an appbar.
- When I do the Flutter inspector, there is nothing in the widget tree that would display like that.

Here's what I've tried and nothing:

- Flutter clean, invalidate caches and restart
- Wipe and delete emulators; create new pixel 3a and 4
- Searched my project for the word 'precheck' and the color '1A1C1E'
- Gone through every file line by line

This is easily the strangest problem I've ever encountered. I'm hoping someone has a solution for how to get rid of it. Thanks

Here is my pubspec.yaml:

[image]

Comment: Can you put other screenshots? The given screenshots is looks blurry so can't identify what you are getting.

Comment: i think its related to your theme check where you used themes

Comment: I put some new screenshots to hopefully make it more clear. I don't see anything in my theme that could cause it. Again, it's not on iOS and not on my 4a.

Comment: Any third-party libraries?

Comment: I just pasted my pubspec.yaml FYI

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed! I found that it was coming from android:label="" in AndroidManifext.xml. When I googled that, I was able to find this post: [Top of the screen when the app is running showing a label with the app title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63459487/top-of-the-screen-when-the-app-is-running-showing-a-label-with-the-app-title).

I had a styles.xml file in the values-night folder, but not the values folder. I just copied and pasted it over and it now works. Don't ask me how that could've happened.

I believe this is the line that does it:

```
<style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
</style>
```